# Regex - Accept AZ excluding some letters for a fixed length

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I can't find how to exclude some chars from fixed length part of a string

with `^XXX-\d{4}-(?![XYT])[A-Z]{4}$`
I can exclude `XYT` from the first char of the last string so

```
XXX-0000-AAAA is ok
XXX-0000-XAAA is not ok
```

my problem is that I do not want `X`, `Y` or `T` in any part of the last segment

```
XXX-0000-AAXA is not ok
XXX-0000-ABXX is not ok
XXX-0000-ABCT is not ok
and so on
```

How can I do that?

To be more precise, I add that XYT are variables, so the solution of a fixed list works but is not convenient

Comment: Olivier, because you admit that you are not skilled enough to understand the differences in the regex patterns (in your comment under Sahil's answer), I have posted an answer that compares all of the answers on this page, so that you can determine for yourself which one is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, This seems to be the most efficient, correct pattern I can make:  ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u80pzw/8))

```
^X{3}-\d{4}-(?![A-Z]{0,3}[XYT])[A-Z]{4}$
```

I have set up a battery of strings to match against which should/does expose any flaws in the patterns posted on this page.  My pattern completes the test in 176 steps and provides correct matching.  This makes it the best pattern that uses a negative lookahead as requested by the OP.

For apples to apples comparison:

> original  190 steps   `^XXX-\d{4}-(?![XYT])[A-Z]{4}$` user1875921     [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u80pzw/5)
>
> incorrect 300 steps   `XXX-\d{4}-(?!.*?[XYT])[A-Z]{4}`        Sahil Gulati    [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u80pzw/7)
>
> correct   140 steps   `^XXX-\d{4}-[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSUVWZ]{4}$`  [commented]     [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u80pzw/1)
>
> correct   245 steps   `^XXX-\d{4}-((?![XYT])[A-Z]){4}$`   Bohemian #1     [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u80pzw/3)
>
> correct   279 steps   `^XXX-\d{4}-(?:(?![XYT])[A-Z]){4}$`     melpomene   [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u80pzw/4)
>
> n/a       -           `^XXX-\d{4}-[A-Z&&[^XYT]]{4}$`      Bohemian #2

Comment: One thing your tests did show is that my answer matched some unwanted characters.  I will amend the answer with acknowledgement

Comment: @hmedia1 I am presenting the facts in the clearest way I can.  My answer was downvoted purely on malice.  I included your other answer because I think someone else had discussed it in a now-deleted comment.  I have logically providen my answer to be superior and I don't want future readers to implement a faulty or inferior snippet.  It is not my post that is confusing -- mine is clear.  Whenever there are several answers that produce the same result, performance should decide what is "best", right?

Comment: @mickmackusa Performance in what regard ?  If you're competing for nanoseconds against a fixed word list counting steps on a web app, I don't think that does anyone justice.  I'm not saying performance isn't important, I'm saying its priority against other factors depends on the application, and many other factors.  Not only that, you can't evaluate performance without understanding how it's going to be used.  So much so to all this that it shouldn't even be a point.

Comment: @hmedia1 I will refer back to my previous argument where I state that when there is a tie on result accuracy, performance should decide the winner.  Nothing emotional about that.

Comment: I referenced your answer in an edit of mine down the bottom, let me know this is ok.

Comment: @hmedia1 wow, I'll start reading that novel now.  I am curious, I wonder if you downvoted my answer?  I have no way of knowing who did it.  I'm assuming it was not you.  If you would like me to edit my answer to remove your earlier typo pattern, I'm happy to do that.  My answer really doesn't deserve to be negative.

Comment: No it doesn't, all I can do is bring it up to 0 until the world sees the light eh. would be appreciated if you removed both references of mine since they are obsolete now.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use `[A-SU-WZ]{4}` for the last part? I.e. only match the letters you want in the first place.

Alternatively, make the look-ahead part of the repetition: `(?:(?![XYT])[A-Z]){4}`

Comment: Hi, yes you're right, it's a simpler way in this case. Problem is that I have several other labels where excluded letters aren't the same. So I hope to find a way to list only those letters + AZ, could be easier to read/check

Comment: @user1875921 Edited.

Comment: @user1875921 This answer is the most efficient way if the blacklisted characters are static.  Even `XXX-\d{4}-[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSUVWZ]{4}` is faster than the other negative matching patterns.  The question should be edited to explain that the blacklisted characters are variable so that readers aren't confused.

Comment: @mickmackusa I added the explaination. Thanks for your expertise and precision, nice job. Olivier

Answer (score 4):

There are two "elegant" ways of doing this. This simplest to understand is:

```
^XXX-\d{4}-((?![XYT])[A-Z]){4}$
```

This is very close to what you had, but instead applies the negative look-ahead to *every* character in the repetition.

The other way is to use a character class *subtraction*:

```
^XXX-\d{4}-[A-Z&&[^XYT]]{4}$
```

You rarely see this syntax used, so it might be good to use if nothing else to impress your colleagues.

Comment: What language supports this subtraction syntax?

Comment: I can't find any information about this `&&` construct. Perl has something similar, but the syntax looks like this: `(?[ [A-Z] & [^XYT] ])`

Comment: @melpomene AFAIK it's standard posix syntax. I know for a fact that java supports it.

Comment: @Bohemian Definitely not POSIX. Seems to be a Java-only extension.

Answer (score 3):

**Regex:** `XXX-\d{4}-(?!.*?[XYT])[A-Z]{4}`

> **1.** `XXX-\d{4}` this will match `XXX-` and then `four digits`
>
> **2.** `(?!.*?[XYT])` negative look ahead for `X` `Y` and `T`
>
> **3.** `[A-Z]{4}` matches `4` characters which can include `A-Z`.

[**Regex code demo**](https://regex101.com/r/9s6JGF/2)

Comment: +1 because it's a good answer and helpful explained.  Just FYI it doesn't work with extended regex, and the last part matches any amount of [A-Z], where the OP may require a strict syntax

Comment: @mickmackusa I for one appreciate seeing a number of ways to achieve the same thing. This answer was explained well, and by changing a + to a {4} would make it spot on, therefore my +1 was supplemented by a comment to that effect.

Comment: Hi to all of you and thanks for all answers. To me this solution works and would like but I'm not skilled enough to understand your experts' discussions. Olivier

Answer (score 2):

## Here is a versatile and fast alternative

**TLDR;** `^XXX-[0-9]{4}-[^XYT -@[-²]{4}$`

The question on this thread highlights a challenge when using regular expressions in a fashion that almost requires "boolean" ways to represent character classes, such as ['A-Z' **but not** 'XYZ'].  For this reason, this answer is presented (as an edit and an update) for the benefit of others facing similar scenarios as the one the OP described.

Given the lack of direct support for a syntax such as ['A-Z' **but not** 'XYZ']; the only way to achieve this type of logic and control the order of precedence for overlapping expressions in a regex is to use features such as [**Lookaround Assertions**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

However, inefficiently applying them can be extremely costly, as pointed out on one of the other answers here.

Here are some ways where the drastic difference in **performance criteria** for an application makes it impossible to have a **generic** regex that achieves this

- The performance of single string matching, where speed differences are un-noticable, may call for a more **reliable** or **robust** regex.  This may be the case for **portability** in code (i.e. almost every regex parser knows what `` [[-\`a-~!-@] `` means, but some don't know what `\W` or `[:punct:]` mean for instance.
- At the other end of the scale, where nanoseconds are critical, then one may wish to re-evaluate many other parts of the process before getting caught up with the regex, but in any case, a very **inflexible** but **high performance** regex might be preferred here, where the system can be made compatible if it isn't already
- The variety of strings has a major impact on performance, and so depending on the application, certain parts of a string can be assessed differently
- For the same reason, the decision of how to structure the **Lookaround** should probably be determined based on the use case.
- Where strings are part of a database and searching is done via an API or other built-in function, specific syntax or format may need to be used.
- Aside from the matching expression, different regex libraries, functions, extensions, can change the entire way a regex is done using options.  For example, the python `re.findall()` can be used as the operational equivalent of a **positive lookbehind** with unknown repetition length.
- Some programs that implement regex are just much faster than others.  This can more than offset the efficiency difference when comparing theoretical steps.

#### Here is a balanced approach to the question:

```
^XXX-[0-9]{4}-[^XYT -@[-²]{4}$
```

Here is an example where **10000 strings are matched** of 10100: https://regex101.com/r/YJ5xME/1

Here is an example where **100 strings are matched** of 10100: https://regex101.com/r/d1l5af/1

There's not a great difference in performance between the two at 10000 strings, by contrast, this regex: `^XXX-[0-9]{4}-([A-Z](?<=[^XYT])){4}$` takes over twice the time to match the 10000 strings.

### This is also compatible with applying an exclude variable as requested

An example on the command line using `bash`:

Take a string file `stringfile`, with contents such as:

- ```
  XXX-0000-SNUR
  XXX-0000-FHDZ
  XXX-0000-+439
  XXX-0000-04X9
  XXX-0000-/1Y+
  XXX-0000-X/X9
  XXX-0000-Y6X9
  XXX-0000-XY16
  XXX-0000-0T94
  XXX-0000-++6Y
  XXX-0000-TT+3
  XXX-0000-NLNL
  XXX-0000-QPSE
  ```

Use of a variable `$exclude` for example:

- ```
  exclude="XYT"
  egrep "^XXX-[0-9]{4}-([^$exclude[^XYT -@[-²]){4}$" < stringfile
  ```

Correct matches:

- ```
  XXX-0000-SNUR
  XXX-0000-FHDZ
  XXX-0000-NLNL
  XXX-0000-QPSE
  ```

### This is also compatible with extended regular expressions

- Use cases like GNU `find` with `-iregex` (if dealing with filenames)
- `egrep` (`grep -E`)
- Anything with support for **Modern Regular Expressions** as defined in **POSIX 1003.2**

### Can I just make the right expression before going to match thousands of lines ?

And here's where efficiency meets accuracy.  Example in the command line:

```
exclude="XYT"
customCharClass="$(
alpha=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
echo "${alpha[@]}" \
| sed -E -e "s/[$exclude]//g")"

egrep "^XXX-[0-9]{4}-([$customCharClass]){4}$" < stringfile
```

Now this is the regex applied to the stringfile:

```
^XXX-[0-9]{4}-([ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSUVWZ]){4}$
```

(Notice there is no **X** **Y** or **T**)

- The example given at the top, accounts for easy portability, quick performance, and accounts for the common use case where extended character sets aren't involved.
- The example here, where a program decides the most effective search criteria, is guaranteed to account for all scenarios
- The tradeoff, and performance evaluation criteria, is the use case.  I.e. generating a custom search string will most certainly take longer for just one string and is by contrast negligable when searching thousands of files.

### There's another answer on this thread that complements this answer.

This regex was posted by @mickmackusa

```
^X{3}-\d{4}-(?![A-Z]{0,3}[XYT])[A-Z]{4}$
```

This regex performs well, is cleaner than the alternative presented in this answer, (It does require PCRE however).

This performs **slightly** slower (but by no means inefficient or wasteful), **but** is guaranteed to produce only an [A-Z] match (with the XYT excluded).

This highlights the need to evaluate the performance criteria specific to the application when designing a regex that may require **lookarounds**

Comment: That is a very well researched and presented post, but why did you stop your list of symbols there?  I mean your pattern will incorrectly match any symbols not in your negative list.  Your comparison against my pattern is not apples to apples.  Did I miss something in that regard?  It was a lot to take in.

Comment: Well a departure from the OP anyhow.

Comment: Your pattern outperforms mine because none of your 10000 input strings expose the fact that your pattern does not strictly adhere to the OP's `A-Z` requirement.  I'll not bother to update my answer to include your new pattern and reveal this -- I think you get it.  My answer remains the best performing, correct pattern that meets the OP's negative lookahead criteria.... and yet, there it is with a negative vote tally and no green tick.  Unjust, I say.

Comment: @mickmackusa I've adjusted it a little bit.  - I cannot see how ``[^XYT -@[-²]``, or the original regex would really be problem, but again my whole answer is about assessing the tradeoff of use.  If one is really that serious about a regex, it stands to reason that an approach similar to the programming generating of string that I showed above would make more sense.  For someone using `busybox` on a router with 4MB flash and no perl, and the character strings were generated by itself anyway - they'd be wrapped with this solution (which performs very well)

Comment: @mickmackusa And... I basically added reference to your answer, as mine didn't cover every single use case.

Comment: @mickmackusa - I found by removing the parenthesis around the character range, it almost halved the steps involved.  At the very least this is one of those patterns that has some use in places where quick subtractive style posix regex is useful

Comment: It is clear to me that you are vastly wiser than me in this domain, so I think it is best that I smile and nod.  I do want to commend you on a thoughtful, well prepared answer.  These kinds of answers provide true value and make SO great.